# Flow type refine mixed to function

Tags: flowtype, koa

I'm using koa which has middleware props typed as mixed, so I'm trying to do something along the lines of the following below but I'm getting an error that `` Cannot call `ctx.render` because  mixed [1] is not a function.Flow(not-a-function) ``

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  // some other code above it
  await ctx.render('index');
});
```

My question is, what's the correct way to do a type refinement that this is a function and then allow me to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refine this to a function, but calling it is another matter.

```js
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  if (typeof ctx.render === 'function') {
    // Now we know that `ctx.render` is a function.
  }
});
```

Flow actually has a special case for this, this is called an "unknown function." We know that `ctx.render` is a function, but we don't know anything about its arguments or return type so we can't safely do anything with it except pass it around. How can we safely call `ctx.render(1)` if we don't know that `ctx.render` takes a `number`?

What's more, we *can't* know anything about it. There is no reflection mechanism provided by JavaScript that we could interrogate for enough information about this function to be able to safely call it. The only thing we can find is the static arity (`ctx.render.length`) but this by itself is not reliable or sufficient.

If we had more information, like say if this were a union type instead of `mixed`, then we could use type refinement to do what we want:

```js
(arg: boolean | (number => void)) => {
  if (typeof arg === 'function') {
    arg(1); // safe because if this is a function, we know it takes a number
  }
};
```

In this case the most reasonable solution is to type through `any`. Assuming that we know that we should only ever receive one type of `render` function, then we just forcibly cast it to that type with all the blaring caveats one would expect:

```js
// I don't know what the type of your render function is, but you would put it
// here:
type RenderFunction = string => void;

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  // some other code above it

  if (typeof ctx.render === 'function') {
    // DANGER: We make a hard assumption here that the render function is
    // always of this specific type. If it is ever of any other type then
    // behavior is undefined!
    await ((ctx.render: any): RenderFunction)('index');
  }
});
```

Also it sounds to me like the koa libdef could probably be improved upon.

Comment: Short answer is you can't then. But appreciate the really detailed answer to why you can't. Guess `any` is the way to go here